# Why the split function in Azure Dataflow Derived column isn't working?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have these messy fields that I need to cleanup in Dataflow. EAN field can have any number of elements separated by ",". But the actual EAN is always the last one. However it seems that there is no way I can get this simple split function to work properly. It always returns only one element with the full content.

What am I doing wrong here?
[image: Debugged result of split, which is not split]

[image: Result of the code that should work]

Comment: can you please add expected output and sample input?

Comment: Examples are on the screenshots. But for example if I have input of "1234, 5678" and I run split("1234, 5678",',') I would assume I would get  array of two elements. Now I get array of one element with both all the original content. So no splitting is happening.

Answer (score 1):

> EAN field can have any number of elements separated by ",". But the actual EAN is always the last one.

To get actual EAN from your all the comma separated value you need to use below expression.

```
split({_col0_}, ",")[size(split({_col0_}, ","))]
```

[image]

Comment: This is similar to what I first had, but then started debugging it and ended up in seeing that split doesn't actually split anything. So I have now this code split({EAN}, ",")[size(split({EAN}, ","))] but the result is still two numbers separated by ','  I will try to add another image to the original description

Comment: your value contain tab maybe it is causing the issue/ can you add source dataset settings?

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. Data source is a long list of excels and yes they contain messy data. I even tried something like this, but still split is not working (though tabs disappear). split(trim(regexReplace({EAN}, '[\\x09\\r\\n\\t]', '')), ",")[size(split(trim(regexReplace({EAN}, '[\\x09\\r\\n\\t]', '')), ","))]

Comment: try thiis expression `split(toString(replace(EAN,'\t','')), ',')`

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this problem was in the messy source data. What I though was a normal comma, wasn't instead it was some strange full width comma eg Unicode Character U+FF0C. The code below made this finally work, it is ugly though.

```
split(trim(regexReplace(regexReplace(EAN, '[\\x09\\r\\n\\t]', ''),'[\\uFF0C]',',')), ",")[size(split(trim(regexReplace(regexReplace(EAN, '[\\x09\\r\\n\\t]', ''),'[\\uFF0C]',',')),','))]
```